# Determine percentage of parallelism of two parallel lines in QGIS/python

Tags: pyqgis, line, spatial-join

I'm trying to match some lines to each other and join attributes proportionally. Have a look at the image where S1 can appear in both A1 and A2. Let's say 30% of S1 is parallel to A1, and 15% of S1 is parallel to A2. Now I have an idea how to match these lines via hub distances in QGIS. But I need to determine the percentage of parallel running segments to say: 30% of S1 is parallel to A1, thus I can relate 30% of N=20 to A1, for example. The hub distance can only match the lineID so I can join the table values without a weight. In the end, I want to calculate a **weighted distribution** along the lines.

[image]

I seek solutions implementable in QGIS, preferably a python algorithm. It should be applicable to  a larger dataset. I have something like this in mind:

```
1. Match segments
2. Determine where overlap exists
3. Apply algorithm to determine the percentage of parallelism of S1 with A1 and A2, resepctively
```

Procedure and results of steps 1 and 2 (Match and determine):

```
1. Locate points along lines (A1 + A2), 5m interval, for example. 
2. Locate points along lines (S1) with larger interval than in first step, e.g., 10m. 
3. Distance to hub with IDs of A1 + A2 as Hubnames. 
4. Count unique IDs (pivot table in excel, avoids counting, thus matching, the same ID to one segment), 
5. If count >1, then S1 parallel to more than one line and it needs weighting smaller than 1. 
6. Based on the IDs I can `join attributes by table` from A1 and A2 and apply the parallelism weight.
```

I only need help for the 3rd step (apply algorithm) as far as I see it now. It is important to have the **percentage of S1** in order to use this percentage as a weight.

Comment: If you have accomplished the first two steps, it would be great if you could edit your question by specifying what will be the input for the third step. I mean: how did you match the segments? How did you determine where the overlap exist? After these analyses, what do you have? A layer with specific fields? Or something else?

Comment: 1. `Locate points along lines` (A1 + A2), 5m interval, for example. 2. `Locate points along lines` (S1) with larger interval than in first step, e.g., 10m. `Distance to hub` with IDs of A1 + A2 as Hubnames. Count unique IDs (pivot table excel, avoids counting, thus matching, the same ID to one segment), if count >1, then S1 parallel to more than one line = needs weighting smaller than 1. Based on the IDs I can `join attributes by table` from A1 and A2 and apply the parallelism weight (the factor I'm looking for).

Comment: In your attached image, different colors mean different layers?

Comment: Yes, that's their meaning.